# Microfrontend: cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations in dynamic import

Tags: micro-frontend

The TS compiler complains about the following code snippet:

```
import('HelloWorldApp/HelloWorldButton')
  .then(HelloWorldButtonModule => {
    const HelloWorldButton = HelloWorldButtonModule.default;
    const helloWorldButton = new HelloWorldButton();
    helloWorldButton.render();
  });
```

this: `Cannot find module 'HelloWorldApp/HelloWorldButton' or its corresponding type declarations`.

Tried adding `declare module 'HelloWorldApp/HelloWorldButton'` to a declaration.d.ts file specified in tsconfig.json but to no avail.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
//types.d.ts inside src folder
 declare module 'host/NewComponent'
```

1. module type declaration problem solved by types.d.ts
2. Please take look properly on config file for host project .
3. I was facing same issues then I used -

   **optimization:{
   splitChunks: false,
   }**
4. you will find **optimization** on vue.config.js file of host project

take a look into the config files -

```
//*vue.config.js* for host project

const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')


const ModuleFederationPlugin =
require("webpack").container.ModuleFederationPlugin;

module.exports = defineConfig({
publicPath:"http://localhost:8000/",
configureWebpack: {
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "host",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      exposes: {
        "./NewComponent": "./src/components/NewComponent.vue",
      },
    }),
  ],
  optimization:{
    splitChunks: false,
}
},
devServer: {
  port: 8000,
},
});
```

Though version doesn't matter here but I want to inform you that I'm using vue 3 .

```
//vue.config.js for consumer project
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')

const ModuleFederationPlugin =
require("webpack").container.ModuleFederationPlugin;

module.exports = defineConfig({
publicPath:"http://localhost:8001/",
configureWebpack: {
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "consumer",
      remotes: {
        host: "host@http://localhost:8000/remoteEntry.js",
      },
    }),
  ],
},
devServer: {
  port: 8001,
},
});
```

And Finally I used the component from host in consumer project.

```
//HelloWorld.vue component in consumer project
<template>
    <div>
     <otherComp></otherComp>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineAsyncComponent, defineComponent } from 'vue';

const otherComp = defineAsyncComponent(() => import("host/NewComponent"));



export default defineComponent({
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  components:{
   otherComp,

  },
  props: {
    msg: String,
  }
});
</script>
```

****Everything is works fine for me .Hoping it will also solve your and others problem to build micro front end . Happy Coding ****